# react controlled input component with local and redux state, how to manage

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, onchange, controlled-component

I have a controlled input component with some action on the value which is passed to local and redux state.
At the moment on the **onchange** event im calling a function which "clean up" the value and then it send it to the **local state** and also send it to the **redux state**, as you can see in the following code.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<Props>): void {

  if (this.props.value !== prevProps.value) {
      this.updateInputValue(this.props.value);
  }
}

handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const value = e.target.value || '';

    if (value === '' || NUMBER_REGEX.test(value)) {
      this.updateInputValue(value);
      this.props.onChange(e);
    }
  };

  updateInputValue = (inputValue: string): void => this.setState({ inputValue });

  onChangeInputField = (e: any): void => {
    const { alphanumeric, uppercase } = this.props;
   

    if (trim) e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '');

    if (alphanumeric && ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP.test(e.target.value)) return;

    if (uppercase) e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();

    this.updateInputValue(e.target.value);

    this.props.onChange(e);
  };
```

My concern here is that:

onChangeInputField triggers:

- updateInputValue which updates state value.
- **props.onChange** which updates redux store value

because something was updated, now we're calling componentDidUpdate which:

- Checks if received props are matching because we updated value in store with props.onChange, we're receiving new prop values
- because of that updateInputValue is once again triggered - which updates state again.

The problems i see here is that first of all we have multiple sources of truth
Secondly i'm rerendering element multiple times.

what would be the correct flow?

Comment: Is there a reason why you not just keep your state only in redux?

Comment: Storing the same state in two places is a terrible idea.

Comment: how would you change it?